# Продление/обновление сертификата ETCD

Tags: kubernetes, x509certificate

Недавно столкнулся с продлением сертификата ETCD. Я хотел продлить сертификаты на 100 лет. Все делал по документации, но не все сертификаты продлились на 100 лет. ca.pem продлился только на 5 лет
`notAfter=Jun  9 09:19:00 2026 GMT`
Можно ли продлить ca.pem на более длительный период?

My config

```
cat ca-config.json 
{
    "signing": {
        "default": {
            "expiry": "876000h"
        },
        "profiles": {
            "server": {
                "expiry": "876000h",
                "usages": [
                    "signing",
                    "key encipherment",
                    "server auth",
                    "client auth"
                ]
            },
            "client": {
                "expiry": "876000h",
                "usages": [
                    "signing",
                    "key encipherment",
                    "client auth"
                ]
            },
            "peer": {
                "expiry": "876000h",
                "usages": [
                    "signing",
                    "key encipherment",
                    "server auth",
                    "client auth"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: это stackoverflow на русском, переведите вопрос, пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Для этого потребовалось изменить ca-csr.json

```
{
    "CA": {
        "expiry": "876000h",
        "pathlen": 0
    },
    "CN": "etcd",
    "key": {
        "algo": "rsa",
        "size": 2048
    }
}
```

А дальше перегинерировать сертификат

`cfssl gencert -initca ca-csr.json | cfssljson -bare ca -`

Смотрим результат
`openssl x509 -enddate -noout -in ca.pem`

`notAfter=May 19 09:26:00 2121 GMT`
Если кому поможет буду рад)